# Is it possible to auto select the mode depending on where the file is?

Tags: major-mode, html

One can use `auto-mode-alist` to define modes based on the regex and the filename. However I want to use different modes for files depending on which folder they are in.

So, for example, in a django project, I might want to use `web-mode` for `*.html` files, but in all other projects, I would want to use the default mode for `*.html` files.

How can I configure emacs to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `auto-mode-alist` to select a mode based on the entire file path, not just the name / extension. The rules are evaluated in order, so you can have an entry to match html files that match some particular parent path and then a more general rule for all other html files based only on the extension.

For example, you could add a rule to remap the html extension for anything under your `projects` directory:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("projects/.*\\.html$" . web-mode))
```

File paths that don't match will fall through to the default html rule.